# model data is null on view postback mvc4 razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a razor view which lists multiple items. On postback I want to have the model from the view so I can get the data, but when I do postback I have a null for model data. I want to know how I can get the data from the view in the controller on submit. 
This is what I have:

View:

```
@using Solution.Web.Models
@model ItemsViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Select Items";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
foreach (var p in Model.Items)
 {
       <div class="well">     
        <span class="pull-right label label-primary">@p.Price.ToString("c")</span>
        <span class="lead"><input type="checkbox" data-id="@p.Id" id="Model.Selected" checked="@p.Selected" value="@p.Id" />   @p.Quantity x @p.Name</span>         
    </div>     
 }   
    <div class="well">        
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Pay with Card</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Pay with PayPal</button>
    </div>

}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
   ItemsViewModel model = new ItemsViewModel
   {
      Items = repository.Items
      .OrderBy(i => i.Id)
      };
      return View(model);
   }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ItemsViewModel items)
{
 return View("NextStep");
}
```

So on HttpPost when I'm getting the model back, I have null. How I can get the correct data set on postback?

This is the ItemsViewModel code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Solution.Domain.Entities;

namespace Solution.Web.Models
{
    public class ItemsViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Item> Items;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for each comment, Laziale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to map your data with the action arguments, your inputs must have their name declared. So change your view like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
for (var i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count(); i++)
 {
       @{
          var p = Model.Items[i];
       }
       <div class="well">     
        <span class="pull-right label label-primary">@p.Price.ToString("c")</span>
        <span class="lead"> @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.Items[i].Selected, new {"data-id" = p.Id })   @p.Quantity x @p.Name</span>         
    </div>     
 }   
    <div class="well">        
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Pay with Card</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Pay with PayPal</button>
    </div>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the id / name attribute of the tags, which you want to serialize to the model's instance. Try changing the id to Items:

```
<span class="lead"><input type="checkbox" data-id="@p.Id" id="Items" checked="@p.Selected" value="@p.Id" />   @p.Quantity x @p.Name</span>
```

I do not know if the input is representing your item, maybe it's your whole div:

```
<div class="well" id="Items">     
   <span class="pull-right label label-primary">@p.Price.ToString("c")</span>
   <span class="lead"><input type="checkbox" data-id="@p.Id" id="Model.Selected" checked="@p.Selected" value="@p.Id" />   @p.Quantity x @p.Name</span>         
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the MVC to generate a checkbox with the control `name` attribute like `Selected[0], Selected[1]`. You need to use the built in MVC helper class like below

```
foreach (var p in Model.Items)
 {
       <div class="well">     
        <span class="pull-right label label-primary">@p.Price.ToString("c")</span>
        <span class="lead">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.Selected,{data_id=m.Id})
        @p.Quantity x @p.Name</span>         
    </div>     
 }
```

**Option 2:**

```
 @counter=1;

 foreach (var p in Model.Items)
 {

       <div class="well">     
        <span class="pull-right label label-primary">@p.Price.ToString("c")</span>
        <span class="lead">
         <input type="checkbox" data-id="@p.Id" id="Model.Selected" 
         checked="@p.Selected" value="@p.Id" name="Selected[@counter]" />  
        @p.Quantity x @p.Name</span>         
    </div>     
    @counter++;
 }
```